# how to append the rows data using sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Test Data

```
Name    count               percentage           location
ABC      2                   100.00%                india
ABC      1                   90.00%                  us
ABC      4                   50.00%                  null
ABC      3                   100.00%                 uk
```

I want to append the count of location null records with india location and need to remove the null records?
Means 3rd row having  location as null then need to append the  count (4) with india  count i.e(2+4=6) .
Please suggest anyone how to achieve this result using sql?

Comment: Can you include your desire output also as table? Will that add alter the percentage?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I think the query generated the above result can be changed. Can you post that

Comment: It will alter the overall percentage also ...

Comment: @Sravanti How will affect percentage? Please show us the logic and the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below solution takes max percentage

```
( select name,count,percentage,location 
  from testdate 
  where location is not null and  location<>'india'  
)
union all
( select name,sum(count),max(percentage),max(location)
  from testdate
  where location='india' or location is null
  group by name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
select name,sum(count),max(percentage),coalesce(location,'India')
from Yourtable
group by name,coalesce(location,'India')
```

Currently it will take the MAX `percentage` out of `NULL` or `India`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `CASE` to change `NULL` to `INDIA`, and then a `GROUP BY` to add the `COUNT`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9b959/6)**

```
SELECT "Name", SUM("count"), MAX("percentage"), "location"
FROM (
     SELECT "Name", 
            "count", 
            CASE WHEN "location" IS NULL THEN ''
                 ELSE "percentage"
            END as "percentage", 
            CASE WHEN "location" IS NULL or "location" = 'india' THEN 'india'
                 ELSE "location"
            END as "location"
     FROM Table1
     ) T
GROUP BY "location", "Name";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Name | sum |     max | location |
|------|-----|---------|----------|
|  ABC |   1 |  90.00% |       us |
|  ABC |   6 | 100.00% |    india |
|  ABC |   3 | 100.00% |       uk |
```

**EDIT:**

The second `CASE` can be replace by

```
COALESCE("location", 'india') as "location"
```